# binding collection obvject in visual basic6

Tags: vb6

i want to use DHTML type of visual basic 6 project to create an html page that can interact with database. msdn have an example in:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229040(v=vs.60).aspx
in this example was used a BindingCollection object,and in my vb6 was not defined such object!
the code is :

```
Dim colBind As BindingCollection

Private Sub DHTMLPage_Load()
' Create a BindingCollection object, then set its
' DataSource property to your data environment and its
' DataMember property to the Customers command object.
Set colBind = New BindingCollection
With colBind
Set .DataSource = MyDataEnvironment
.DataMember = "Customers"

' Bind the Value property of elements on the HTML page
' to fields in the Customers recordset.
.Add CustomerID, "Value", "CustomerID"
.Add CompanyName, "Value", "CompanyName"
.Add Address, "Value", "Address"
.Add City, "Value", "City"
.Add Region, "Value", "Region"
.Add PostalCode, "Value", "PostalCode"
.Add Country, "Value", "Country"
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the BindingCollection object's type library to your project. 
To add the reference, select References on the Project menu, then select Microsoft Data 
Binding Collection in the References dialog box.